# How to implement collapsable listview?

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, header

I want to implement similar collapsable/foldable functionality in android.

[image: Here]

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ExpandableListView in android](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html). Go through the documentation. 
[Example here](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/)

Comment: But I need all header stick on top as shown in image(Nonscrollable).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use expandable ListView for this. 
You can follow this tutorials for it.

[Expandable List view Example](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html)

[Expandable List view Example2](http://www.learn-android-easily.com/2013/07/android-expandablelistview-example.html)

Comment: But I need all header stick on top as shown in image(Nonscrollable).

Comment: Yes,but on scroll group header is also scrolled and I need to stick that header on top.